# Trying to create a C program that finds the reverse of a string word by word

Tags: c

**So here i really don't know why it is not working , when i try to type hellow world i get the result : woll dlrl , i have 0 idea why , please help ...**
i think the problem has to do with something related to \0 or something i didnt pay attention or i simply didn't know , the program works without errors but it doesnt give me what i want

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  char S[250] = {};
  char arr_R[250] = {};
  int start = 0, end = 0, space_loc = 0; // start represents the starting index
                                         // of a word in the string , similar
                                         // thing goes for end .

  // space_loc determines the index when the program finds a space of a \0 to
  // try sperate words.
  gets(S);

  for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++) { // it won't actually go for 250 times loop ,
                                  // the program will end when it sees '\0'

    if (S[i] == ' ') {

      space_loc = i;
      end = i - 1;
      for (int j = 0; j <= (end - start) + 1; j++) {
        arr_R[j] = S[end];
        end--;

        printf("%c", arr_R[j]);
      }

      strcpy(arr_R, ""); // here i am emptying the string arr_R but i dont think
                         // it's necessary at all since the overwriting and
                         // printing process will iterate over (end-start)+1
                         // which represents the new word that the program
                         // reversed and copied to arr_R
      printf("%c", S[space_loc]); // just printing the space
      start = space_loc + 1;
    }

    if (S[i] == '\0') {

      space_loc = i;
      end = i - 1;
      for (int j = 0; j <= (end - start) + 1; j++) {
        arr_R[j] = S[end];
        end--;
        printf("%c", arr_R[j]);
      }

      strcpy(arr_R, "");
      printf("%c", S[space_loc]);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use proper indentation. And don't use `gets`.

Comment: okay then what should i use other than gets , i am pretty noob at coding so i need more guidance , i heard scanf stops on spaces ' ' and so i can't input a sentence but only i word, and what does proper indentation even mean ?

Comment: `fgets` is safer version of it

Comment: didn't solve the problem ,in such simple program , gets will do just fine , there are no complications for using it in this situation , problem still unsolved

Answer (score 0):

Try this version : I essentially removed duplication of codes by regrouping the test for `' '` and `'\0'`, removed the flushing of arr_R that was wrong and useless, and made some other cosmetic changes replacing `for` loops by `while` loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char S[250] = {};
    char arr_R[250] = {};
    int start = 0, end = 0, i=0, j, space_loc = 0, isEnd = 0;
    
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", S);
    while (!isEnd)
    {
        isEnd = S[i] == '\0';
        if (S[i] == ' ' || isEnd) 
        {
            space_loc = i;
            end = i - 1;
            j = 0;
            while (end >= start) {
                arr_R[j] = S[end--];
                printf("%c", arr_R[j]);
                j++;
            }
            start = space_loc + 1;
            
            if (isEnd) printf("\n");
            else printf("%c", S[space_loc]);
            
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output when tested with "hello world" :

```
olleH dlrow
```